# first parent ul and first li doesn't work properly

Tags: css, html

I have an issue when selecting the first `ul` and its first `li` but it affects the first `li` of the second `ul>li` too.

My attempt:

```
#main-nav ul:first-child li:first-child{
    border-radius:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

The corresponding html:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Gallery 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Gallery 2</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
     <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code its not `fist` its `first`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are after is:

```
#main-nav ul:first-child > li:first-child {
   border-radius:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

This will only select the first `li` of the first `ul` as `>` selects only child elements of the element preceding it.

As Paulie_D suggests, `#main-nav > ul > li:first-child` is a bit more concise and will also work as long as there is just the one child `ul` in `#main-nav`.

Comment: `#main-nav > ul > li:first-child` would be even shorter. although it does assume there is only one `ul` direct child.

Comment: I do agree that which takes the direct child of `#main-nav`

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, that would be a bit more concise in this instance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
#main-nav ul:first-of-type > li:first-child{
    border-radius:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
```

Refer to this [**link**](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)